# Fix the x & y axis of popup in a swf file that is being loaded in another swf file

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I load a "cal" swf file in another swf files mdi_window. So the window is moveable inside the application.

The issue is with the x y axis for the popups that open up in cal swf. 
The code for the function that opens popup is:

```
private var eventPanel:ElixirEventPanel = null;
        private function showEventEditPanel(item:CalendarItem,x:int,y:int):void{            
            eventPanel = ElixirEventPanel.sharedInstance;       
            eventPanel.setStyle("modalTrasparancy",0);
            eventPanel.setStyle("modalTransparencyBlur",0);
            eventPanel.setStyle("modalTransparencyColor",0xffffff);
            eventPanel.setStyle("modalTransparencyDuration",0);
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(eventPanel,DisplayObject(super), false);       
            eventPanel.calendarItem = item;

            eventPanel.x = x - eventPanel.width;
            eventPanel.y = y - eventPanel.height/2;
            if(eventPanel.y < this.parent.scaleY + 100)
                eventPanel.y = this.parent.scaleY + 100;


        }
```

Now as this swf is being loaded in another file using : (as you can see I am trying to convert the local co-ordinates to Global, using localToGlobal function, but I guess I am doing something wrong in that)

```
<s:SWFLoader id="template" source="Cal.swf" loadForCompatibility="true" width="100%"  height="100%" scaleContent="true" complete="dump(event);"/>
<fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[   
        private function dump(event:Event): void {              
            var panel:MovieClip = MovieClip(template.content);
            var pt:Point = panel.localToGlobal(new Point(panel.x, panel.y));                
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

The x & y axis of the popup act wired based on the location of the mdi_window in which the Cal.swf is being loaded. The x & y axis work fine if I move the mdi_window all the way on the top left corner of the application.

The first image shows how the popup opens when I double-click on the 10:00 AM purple color event on my calendar.  [image]

and now when I move my window the popup moves to the side as well. I clicked on the same 10:00Am purple event again here: [image]
How can I solve this issue.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Best
Zee

Comment: What is your issue?  It relates to the x,y axis of the popup.  But, what exactly is wrong with them?  Perhaps a screenshot of what is happening vs what you want to be happening would be beneficial.

Comment: Updated pictures. Does this explains a bit more what my issue is?

Comment: That helps significantly.  Other than to tell you that need to calculate the position of the popup relative to the module's position [not relative to the main app] I don't have specifics for you.  Very Nice Calendar style UI, BTW.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying the fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [localToGlobal()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#localToGlobal%28%29) to translate a local point to a global point? It should work but I've never tried it with SWFLoader.